# Python RegEx with word boundaries

Tags: python, regex, authentication

I am trying to write a login routine for a python script.  In doing so, I find the need to pattern match the credentials on a whole word basis.  I have attempted to RegEx this, but it is failing for reasons that are unclear to me, but I hope are obvious to someone here.  The code and output:

```
import re

authentry = "testusertestpass"
username = "testuser"
password = "testpass"
combo = "r\'\\b"+username + password + "\\b\'"
testcred = re.search(combo, authentry)
print combo
print authentry
print testcred

r'\btestusertestpass\b'
testusertestpass
None
```

So my regex test appears, at least to me, to be properly formatted, and should be a direct match against the test string, but is not.  Any ideas?  Thanks so much for any insight!

Comment: `r'\b' + username + password + r'\b'` `r` before a string literal means raw string literal, which has a slightly different parsing rule.

Answer (score -1):

**try this:** it may works.

```
import re

authentry = "testusertestpass with another text"
username = "testuser"
password = "testpass"
combo = username + password + r'\b'
testcred = re.search(combo, authentry)
print combo
print authentry
print testcred
```

**output:**

```
testusertestpass\b
testusertestpass with another text
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1b8a030>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment!  While this does indeed give a match, it also matches on any subset of the string "testusertestpass" such as "testusertestpas"

Comment: then, only use `username + password`. And clear to me with input & output